# Can I travel to Germany with Italian MAE special ID card issued by government to certain categories of foreign nationals?

Tags: germany, italy

I have a valid *Carta d'Identità per organizzazioni internazionali o missioni estere speciali* issued by Italian MAE. Can I travel to Germany with this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Carta d’Identità per organizzazioni internazionali o missioni estere speciali

Answer (score 3):

From the description, this sounds more like proof that you are employed by the Ministry of Foreign Affairs and not in itsself a travel document.

This card can used **togeather** with your passport to all Schengen Countries.

This is something you should really ask your employer and not here.

---

> Carta d'identità M.A.E.
>   (Identity Card issued by the Ministry of Foreign Affairs)
>
> Mod. 11 (beige) Funzionari delle **Organizzazioni internazionali**, Consoli Onorari, impiegati locali, personale di servizio assunto all'estero e venuto al seguito, familiari Corpo Diplomatico e Organizzazioni Internazionali titolari di passaporto ordinario
>
> (Model 11 (beige) Officials of international organisations, honorary consuls, local employees, domestic staff recruited abroad who have followed their employer, families of members of the diplomatic corps and international organisations **who hold an ordinary passport**)

---

> > NB: Models 6 (orange) and 9 (green) for, respectively, staff of international organisations who have no immunity and foreign honorary consuls, are no longer issued and have been replaced by **model 11**. However, these documents remain valid until the expiry date stated on them.
> >
> > On the back of the identify card it is stated that the card exempts the holder from the requirement to hold a residence permit and, **together with a valid travel document**, entitles the holder to enter the territory of any Schengen state.

---

**Sources**:

- [ANNEX 20 SPECIMEN OF CARDS ISSUED BY FOREIGN MINISTRIES OF THE MEMBER STATES - Part 1](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_20_part1.pdf)
- [ANNEX 20 SPECIMEN OF CARDS ISSUED BY FOREIGN MINISTRIES OF THE MEMBER STATES - Part 2](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_20_part2.pdf)